# Sorting a List - How to?

Tags: java, android, list, sorting, arraylist

I have three object classes called `Size1`, `Size2`, `Size3`

All Size classes has different values (all Values are Strings):

- Size1.getValue() = "1"
- Size2.getValue() = "2"
- Size3.getValue() = "1"

I want to sort a List so that it wouldn't contain duplicate values.

Here it is what I tried:

```
private List<Size> getSortedSizes(List<Size> allSizes){

  List<Size> sortedArray = new ArrayList<>();

  for (int i = 0; i < allSizes.size(); i++){
    Size size = allSizes.get(i);
    if (sortedArray.size() == 0){
      sortedArray.add(Size);
    } else {
      for (int a = 0; a < sortedArray.size(); a++) {
        if (!sortedArray.get(a).getValue().equals(Size.getValue())) {
          sortedArray.add(Size);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return sortedArray;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to sort the list or delete all duplicates from the list? There is quite a difference between the two operations.

Comment: Delete all duplicates

Comment: Please provide a complete example that we can compile and run ourselves. Show how you create the List and call this method.

Comment: Then I would recommend using a Set. Because thats what Sets are for (containing no duplicates). But take note that you need your Size class to have implemented the  equals() and hashcode() methods for it to work correctly with a Set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement your method in the following way:

```
private Set<Size> getSortedSizes(List<Size> allSizes) {
    Set<Size> sorted = new TreeSet<>(sortedArray);
    return sorted;
}
```

But you have to implement two methods in your Size class, they are: *hashCode()* and *int compareTo(Object o)* from the *Comparable* interface

Answer (score 3):

Add to a TreeSet, not an Arraylist

TreeSets are ordered and cannot contain duplicates